# Getting the assembly code of clock_gettime using valgrind?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, valgrind, system-calls

Consider the following code:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const std::size_t n = argc > 1 ? std::atol(argv[1]) : 65536;
    struct timespec tp;
    volatile std::size_t x = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);
        x += tp.tv_nsec;
    }
    return x;
}
```

which is a test code that is just calling `clock_gettime`, `n` times. Currently, I am compiling it with:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++11 -O3 clock_gettime.cpp -o clock_gettime
```

and I am analyzing the code with:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --dump-instr=yes --collect-jumps=yes ./clock_gettime 100000
```

However, valgrind cannot access the inner assembly code of `clock_gettime` as shown below:
[image: clock_gettime asm]

How can I access the assembly code that is actually executed? (either by using compiler flags or by other flags for valgrind)

Comment: You mean the kernel code that you call with `syscall`?  Are you using old hardware or something, without `constant_tsc` and `nonstop_tsc`?  Normally `clock_gettime` runs in user-space without entering the kernel, just using the VDSO pages exported by the kernel into user-space.  (which run `rdtsc`).  But IIRC, even on new hardware it can fall back to making a system call in some cases.  Maybe that happens when valgrind single-steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I access the assembly code that is actually executed?

You *are* accessing the code that is *actually* executed under Valgrind, namely:

```
mov $_NR_clock_gettime, %eax
syscall
```

Valgrind [zaps](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=valgrind.git;a=blob;f=coregrind/m_initimg/initimg-linux.c;h=30e1f850f04ab9dc329290986b606ca6ed30ae15;hb=504dfff68548e424a39801eb750d869316eb3b95#l794) `AT_SYSINFO_EHDR` from the `auxv[]` vector, and so GLIBC behaves as if  vdso (and `__vdso_clock_gettime` in it) do not exist.